# Combine strings and filename modifiers in nmap

Tags: vim

Is it possible to combine strings and filename modifiers in a vim `nmap` command?

I have the following in my `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <D-F4> :TlistAddFiles %:p:h *.*<CR>
```

I wish to have an analogue that is restricted to the current filetype.

For example, if the current file was `/Users/me/Py/project1/myFile.py`, the command would add all the `.py` files in the `/Users/me/Py/Project1/` directory to the `Taglist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just stick them all together - `vim` can tell which bit to expand and which is the string.  For the task in question, use the following:

```
nnoremap <D-F4> :TlistAddFiles %:p:h/*.%:e
```

If the current file is an `.py` file, only `.py` files will be indexed.

See `:help %:e` for more on filename modifiers.